# Android Autoについて

Tags: android

現在 Android Autoはまだまだ未公開の部分です。
私は、Android Phone側のアプリではなく、車載器側のAndroid Autoを
動かしてみたいと考えています。もしくはビルドしたいと考えています。

現在公開されている範囲ですと、上記のようなことはできないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

結論から言うと、車載器側のアプリが存在しません。

Android Autoはただ Android Phoneの extensionです。画面レンダーやタッチ入力などが、車載器側ではなく、携帯端末側で処理しています。つまり外部モニタみたい物です。（SonyのLiveView見たい）

この時点で開発出来る Auto用アプリは`メディア／音楽アプリ`と`メッセージアプリ`２種類しかありません。Viewの自定義などは一切できない状態です。詳細はこちらへ：https://developer.android.com/training/auto/index.html